# How to get data from JS onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick

The site has a button that, when clicked, data is displayed. Can I somehow get the data without pressing the button?

```
<script>
document.write("<a href=\"javascript://\" onClick=\"contacts('ndTh6ffu77AKIx8ZpViA','','l8Guv6K3of94ckBN9AaWtc89','l8bx4vzs9qIM',''); return false;\" style=\"text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted\" rel=\"nofollow\">Показать контактную информацию</a>");
</script>
<a rel="nofollow" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted" onclick="contacts('ndTh6ffu77AKIx8ZpViA','','l8Guv6K3of94ckBN9AaWtc89','l8bx4vzs9qIM',''); return false;" href="javascript://"></a>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; under what circumstances do you want to get the data without pressing the button?

Answer (score 0):

Just take the function in this case:

```
contacts('ndTh6ffu77AKIx8ZpViA','','l8Guv6K3of94ckBN9AaWtc89','l8bx4vzs9qIM','');
```

and place it in the console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Hopefully, if the function doesn't distinguishes between calling via clicking and manual calling, you will get your results.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use data attributes

```
<a rel="nofollow" id="my-button" data-a="ndTh6ffu77AKIx8ZpViA" data-b="l8Guv6K3of94ckBN9AaWtc89" data-c="l8bx4vzs9qIM" data-d="" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted" onclick="contacts('ndTh6ffu77AKIx8ZpViA','','l8Guv6K3of94ckBN9AaWtc89','l8bx4vzs9qIM',''); return false;" href="javascript://"></a>
```

then:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("my-button")
btn.dataset.a=="ndTh6ffu77AKIx8ZpViA" //true
//etc..
```